# Illustrator: How to stretch or resize multiple objects relative to each other

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, workflow, scale

#### #1. Original Illustration

The grey circles are ~ 15 × 15 pt.

[image]

---

#### #2. Scaled Together

The grey circles are resized to ~ 25 × 25 pt.
They're all selected or grouped together, and values collectively changed in the ***Properties*** panel, or stretched using the mouse
(<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> | <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd> to maintain centre & constrain proportions).
Single operation.

[image]

---

#### #3. Scaled Individually

The grey circles are resized to ~ 25 × 25 pt.
Each object maintains its own unique centre point.
Same method as before, but this time each one was resized individually.
Fifteen operations.

[image]
*<sup>note: text objects were scaled & moved separately.</sup>*

---

#### The Question:

Quick and easy is **#2**, but the gaps between the objects increase and the objects fall out of bounds. The desired result is **#3**, but it gets  monotonous fast and can be time-consuming. Is there a shortcut, or key combination, etc. or some quick, cohesive way to get the same result?

Comment: Transform each. But yes you are using a direct modeler after all.

Answer (score 2):

- Select the circles
- **Menu Effect** > **Convert to Shape** > **Ellipse...**
- Set the new size, with **Absolute** checked > Ok
- **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't even know that was an option. It's weird because there's also **Object > Shape > Convert to Shape** which seems to do nothing. Anyway, why **Expand Appearance** at the end?

Comment: To get the vector anchor points if necessary but it's not obligatory.

Comment: I know you shouldn't say it, but this is an incredibly useful answer. I had literally hundreds of points I needed to resize to make a diagram consistent. This saved my life!